# PHP/Manual use of images? - 2 Questions

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, gallery, media, wp-insert-post

I've made a quick PHP script/page that uses the wp_insert_post() function to insert a post directly.  And this works great.  The post I am manually adding has an image in it, so I firstly manually/programatically upload the image to the respective "/uploads/" folder where all my post images are saved (btw im not using year/month sub-directories).  The content of the post has normal text, plus the necessary HTML to point to the image too, eg.

```
<p>This is a manually created post for my blog, there should be a picture below this line of text.  Thanks for visiting.</p>
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg">
```

The post appears fine (including the image).  But my 2 problems are:

1) The image I uploaded is not in the Media Library, How do I get it in there?

2) I would like to add a "featured image/thumbnail" to the same image, but I dont know what function is used to make that call?  I was hoping to find a function along the lines of insert_featured_thumbnail("/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg", $pid)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

WizzKidd

Answer (score 3):

[Function Reference/wp insert attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

```
$image_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
```

This function will return an image id which you can use for the featured image.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "_thumbnail_id", $image_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer. It was spot on. I'm now using the following code:

```
//SAVE THE POST - $new_post is my array that conforms to the necessary requirements
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

//SET MY TAGS UP PROPERLY - $tagsArray contains an array of tags
wp_set_post_tags($pid, $tagsArray);

//ADD IMAGE TO IMAGE-GALLERY AND return $image_id - $wp_image is my image filename
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($wp_image), null);
$attachment = array(
   'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
   'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $myImageTitle),
   'post_content'   => '',
   'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);
$serverFullPath = '/home/user/public_html/mysite/wp-content/uploads/';
$image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $serverFullPath . $wp_image, $pid);

//ADD THE MEDIA GALLERY IMAGE AS A FEATURED IMAGE FOR THIS POST
update_post_meta($pid, "_thumbnail_id", $image_id);

//POST THE POST
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

I checked the Media Gallery, and my image is there :) although it doesn't specify the author of the file unlike the other images which show 'admin'.

Thanks for your help.